# UI Navigation Bar Image Title

Tags: ios, image, swift, uinavigationbar

How can I set the title of a `UINavigationBar` to be an image using Swift.

For example, Instagram does the following:

[image]

**Objective**: Find how to set the title of a `UINavigationBar` to be an image using Swift.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
var titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "nameOfTheImage.ext"))
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

To fits the the image in the dimension you want you have to do the follwoing :

```
var titleView : UIImageView
// set the dimensions you want here
titleView = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 70))
// Set how do you want to maintain the aspect
titleView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
titleView.image = UIImage(named: "nameOfTheImage.ext")

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

Comment: Alright that works. Do you know the dimensions that the image should be as it is currently oversized and does not fit but appears.

Comment: It should be fit the size of the image you pass, you don't need to set it

Comment: The image is to big, so I would like to reset the dimensions of the image before I pass it into Xcode.

Comment: The image isn't completely centered

Comment: @StevenR I'm afraid to you have to play with the contentMode and see it how to center in the container, sorry but I answer your question already. I hope you understand

Comment: I recommend you set another question with you issue